# Failure to try to remove item not in LInkedList in C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

In a simple LinkedList class, I'm trying to remove an object and when the item is there it works fine but when I try to remove an item that isn't there, my program terminates and says that it just has stopped working... Posted below is the code. Any suggestions?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(){
        data=-1;
        next=NULL;
    }
    Node(int d){
        data=d;
        next=NULL;
    }
    Node(int d, Node* n){
        data=d;
        next=n;
    }
};
class LinkedList{
    public:
    Node* head;
    Node* dummy = new Node();
    LinkedList(){
        head=dummy;
    }
    LinkedList(Node* n){
        head=dummy;
        dummy->next=n;
    }
    void ins(Node* n){
        Node* current = head;
        while(current->next!=NULL&&current->next->data<=n->data){
            current=current->next;
        }
        n->next=current->next;
        current->next=n;
    }
    void print(){
        Node* current = head;
        while(current->next!=NULL){
            cout<<current->next->data<<endl;
            current=current->next;
        }
    }
    int peek(){
        if(head->next==NULL){
            cout<<"List is Empty"<<endl;
        }
        return head->next->data;
    }
    void rem(int toRemove){
        Node* current = head;
        while(current->next!=NULL&&current->next->data!=toRemove){
            current=current->next;
        }
        if(current->next->data==toRemove){
            current->next=current->next->next;
            cout<<"Removing Item"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        if(current->next->data!=toRemove){
            cout<<"No Item Found"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        if(current->next==NULL){
            cout<<"Not Removable since not there"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
LinkedList* a = new LinkedList();
Node* n = new Node(5);
Node* nn = new Node(10);
Node* nnn = new Node(15);
Node* nnnn = new Node(12);
Node* nnnnn = new Node(7);
a->ins(n);
a->ins(nn);
a->ins(nnn);
a->ins(nnnn);
a->ins(nnnnn);
a->print();
a->rem(5);
a->print();
a->rem(13);
a->print();
return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: My suggestion is that you run in a debugger.

Comment: I also suggest you look over your logic again, both of the loop and the checks afterward. What do you think will happen when the loop runs to its end (when the first condition is true) because the item isn't found?

Comment: Why the hell do you need a dummy node?

Comment: Dummy is there to cut down on the insertion and deletion cases

Answer (score 2):

In your rem() function, your while loop gets you safely to a node that is not null, but after the while loop you don't check to see if current->next is not null. If it is null, you will crash when dereferencing current->next->data. Which is what happened when I ran your code.

I would suggest loop until you FIND the one to remove, not loop while you DON'T find it -- you may never find it.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After this loop:

```
   while(current->next!=NULL&&current->next->data!=toRemove){
        current=current->next;
```

you can have two situation:

- You've found your data:
- or `current->next==NULL` because you managed to arrive at end of the list

The next statement you execute is

```
    if(current->next->data==toRemove){
```

But if `current->next` was `NULL` you try to dereference a null pointer and get your segfault !  You have to first check that you're not at NULL.

Edit:  Once you've corrected this, I believe there's other issues you have to think of:

- <strike>what if you want to delete the first element ?  You don't foresee to update `head` when this happens. Anyway, as you start to lookig at the next data, you'll miss it.</strike> *Sorry, I didn't notice the dummy node ;-)*
- Your three `if` seem to be mutually exclusive, so you should connect them with an `else`